# Splash screen with progress indicator on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, screen, splash-screen

I am trying to design a splash screen with an activity indicator on it.
I am successfully creating a splash screen but my indicator is not being added to it,
it is being hidden below the image while i am setting its layout.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
package mypackage;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.progressindicator.ActivityIndicatorController;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.progressindicator.ActivityIndicatorModel;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.progressindicator.ActivityIndicatorView;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
//import net.rim.device.api.ui.extension.container.EyelidFieldManager;


public final class SplashScreen extends SplashScreenPage
{


    public SplashScreen()
    {        
     super(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("splash-blackberry.png"),2);
    }
}
class SplashScreenPage extends MainScreen

{   

    VerticalFieldManager vfm= new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER);


HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER)
    {
        protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
     {
        super.sublayout(360,60);
        setExtent(360, 60);

       Field field = getField(0);
       layoutChild(field,140, 60);
       setPositionChild(field, 100,200);
 }



    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
     {
         //Draw the background image and then call paint.

     // super.paint(graphics);
      //graphics.clear();

         // graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
          //graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 360, 480, popup, 0, 0);

             // super.paint(graphics);
             // graphics.clear();       
         // graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 360, 480, popup, 0, 0);


    }               

    };





    ActivityIndicatorView view = new ActivityIndicatorView(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    ActivityIndicatorModel model = new ActivityIndicatorModel();
    ActivityIndicatorController controller = new ActivityIndicatorController();






    boolean notlogged = false;
    Bitmap popup;
    SplashScreenPage screen1 = this;
    private Timer splashTimer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask splashTask;
    int count = 0;
    int screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = Display.getHeight();
    int yCoord;
    int xCoord;
    boolean showSplash = true;
    boolean splashDisplayed = false;
    //SplashScreen page is here
    public SplashScreenPage(Bitmap popup, final int seconds) 
    {

        view.setController(controller);
        view.setModel(model);
        view.setLabel("Loading");
        controller.setModel(model);
        controller.setView(view);

        model.setController(controller);        

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("images.jpeg");
        view.createActivityImageField(bitmap, 5, Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);

      //  add(view);

   add(hfm);
    hfm.add(view);
  // add(vfm);
   // vfm.add(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("splash-blackberry.png"));






          this.popup = popup;
          xCoord = (screenWidth - popup.getWidth()) / 2;
           yCoord = (screenHeight - popup.getHeight()) / 2;

            splashTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                if (showSplash && !splashDisplayed) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == seconds * 15) {
                        showSplash = false;
                        splashDisplayed = true;
                        splashTimer.cancel();
                        invalidate();


                        synchronized (Application.getEventLock()){

                             UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new secondscreen());
                              notlogged = true;
                             }

                       }
                }
            }
        };

       splashTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(splashTask, 100, 100);

    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        if (showSplash && !splashDisplayed) {
            graphics.drawBitmap(xCoord, yCoord, popup.getWidth(), popup.getHeight(), popup, 0, 0);
           // super.paint(graphics);
           // graphics.clear();
        }
    }

    protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
        showSplash = true;
        invalidate();
        super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
    }


    protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
        return DismissSplash();
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        return DismissSplash();
    }

        protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {
        return DismissSplash();
    }

    private boolean DismissSplash() {
        if (showSplash) {
            showSplash = false;
            splashDisplayed = true;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void onExposed() {
           if( notlogged)
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HorizontalFieldManager that you are adding view to, you need to make sure you are calling super.paint() because it called subpaint() which will tell its child Fields (view in this case) to paint themselves. I see that you have it commented out, so you've probably been messing with that. Also, be sure that you do your background painting before you call super.paint() so you don't cover up the ActivityIndicatorView with your own painting.

Would it be possible for you to go through and clean up the code (removing the commented out code that isn't important) to a point where you would expect it to work so it is a littler easier to distinguish between "trying anything you can" code and "working" code.

Comment: can you please show how to use subpaint method in the above code so that i could show my activity indiactor on saplash screen. thanks in advance,,,,

Comment: subpaint() simply goes through the child fields and calls paintChild() on them. If you call super.subpaint() from your paint call you shouldn't have to actually implement it.